# Converting array element to string in VB (using Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

So I'm trying to set up a VB Windows Form that reads data from an array and displays it in a label (and sometimes textboxes so it could be edited). The array contains strings and I know they are stored properly because I can make them appear properly when using MsgBox.

For example

```
MsgBox(ArrayName(0,0))
```

works, but when I use

```
textboxname.Text = ArrayName(0,0)
```

I get a build error. I thought adding ".ToString" at the end might solve this, and the build error is gone, but then the textbox says "System.Char[]" instead of the value that I put inside the array. The MsgBox shows this as well, if I put ".ToString" at the end.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit: The array is declared via the code:

```
Module ModuleName
Public ArrayData(20, 6) As Array
End Module
```

so that I can edit it outisde of any specific subroutines.

The array only contains the characters (delimiter is comma): 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 in the first row and q,w,e,r,t,y in the second row.

Comment: It would help to know how the array is declared and what is in it

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the original post to include that information.

Comment: Please show the code how you init your array.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not familiar with jargon, so I just added all of the code where the array is mentioned (which is only a single segment).

Comment: I suspect you want `Public ArrayData(20, 6) As String`. Otherwise, you can construct a string from an array of chars with `New String(ArrayData(0, 0))`. Finally, use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to avoid any unexpected conversions, as it appears that you did not intend to convert the values of `NowField` to character arrays.

Comment: Thank you. Using Public ArrayData(20, 6) As String worked fixed my problem. I'm not sure I understand what delcaring as string means in this case, though. Isn't a string just a piece of text and an array is a list with multiple possible dimensions?